# coffee script not showing ajax status message

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
->
    $('#new_category').bind "ajax:beforeSend", ->
        notification = 'test'
        $('#notification').html notification
```

The above code generates js code of

```
(function() {
  return $('#new_category').bind("ajax:beforeSend", function() {
    var notification;
    notification = 'test';
    return $('#notification').html(notification);
  });
});
```

But the element with id notification is empty it is not working.

Comment: What exactly do you want the code to do? Why are you setting the `notification` variable and then not use it anywhere?

Comment: edited my question check it

Comment: @Seting See my answer for the "correct" way to do a document ready with coffeescript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do a few things:

1. Run this code when the DOM is ready
2. Use `.on()` in place of `.bind()` if you are using jQuery 1.7+
3. As @cuberto pointed out, you'll want to use the global `ajaxSend` event

So your code should look like:

```
$ ->
    $('#new_category').on "ajaxSend", ->
        notification = 'test'
        $('#notification').html notification
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating a function expression, not actually running it anywhere. Also, I'm not sure where you got that event name? [Here is the list of jQuery AJAX events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/), I think you want the global `'ajaxSend'` event. Try this:

```
do ->
  $('#new_category').on 'ajaxSend', ->
    notification = 'test'
    $('#notification').html notification
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with document.ready function

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('#new_category').on "ajaxSend", ->
        notification = 'test'
        $('#notification').html notification
```

I hope this helps

Comment: That's not the coffeescript way, though... See my answer.